# Cat and human brains and nervous systems are wired together to fight evil rat-like beings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

Looking for this story for a while. Probably from an anthology. Read this many years ago. Earth is under attack by creatures that I recall are on a non-physical plane. Sentient cat brains are wired into the fighter ships to meld with the human co-pilot, taking advantage of the cat's superior nervous system and predator instincts. The bad guys appear to be rat-like - or made to look like that by the ship's software to entice the cat fighter to engage. A fun concept, but the real story is a love story: The human protagonist is falling in love with his feline fighting partner. As I recall, he is married, and his wife is becoming more suspicious. I loved how it described the cat's fighting instincts and why the man loves her.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect you are talking about [The Game of Rat and Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_of_Rat_and_Dragon), by Paul Linebarger (aka Cordwainer Smith.)

Do the names Underhill, Lady May, Woodley, Father Moontree, or West ring any bells?

From the Wikipedia article: "Cats guided by telepaths are used to fight the "dragons", because of their very quick reactions. They see the aliens as giant rats, hence the story title."

Re: the romantic side: "Underhill is hospitalized and a doctor tells him that he was within a tenth of a millisecond of going insane, but the only thing that concerns Underhill is his partner, Lady May, and her well-being. A secretly jealous and angry nurse walks in and Underhill compares her to Lady May. Logically, he understands that Lady May is only a cat, but his mind tells him that no woman will ever equal her."

Comment: Thank you very much! Lady May immediately rang a bell.